# SQL Trigger for maintaining modification history

Tags: sql, triggers

I have three tables:

```
Table1: Customers (CustomerId, Name, CustomerAddress)
Table2: AccountManagers(ManagerId, Name)
Table3: CustomerAccountManagers (CustomerId, ManagerId, Remarks)
Table4: CustomerHistory(CustomerAddress, ManagerId, Date)
```

The CustomerHistory table is used to store any changes made to "CustomerAddress" OR "ManagerId" for example CustomerAddress is updated from "Address1" to "Address2" OR The CustomerAccountManager changes from "Manager1" to "Manager2".

I need to store the changes in CustomerHistory table through SQL Trigger. The issue is that the on which table should i have my trigger? Please note that the changes are made at the same time to both the tables "Customers" & "CustomerAccountManagers".

Thanks

Comment: You might find Googling for techniques for implementing a type 4 slowly changing dimension helpful (see the different types here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the `CustomerHistory` table should probably contain `CustomerId` as well, so that a history record can be tracked back to the proper customer.

You'll need two triggers: one on `CustomerAccountManagers` and one on `Customers`. If you can guarantee the order in which they are executed it's fine: the first trigger will insert, the second update the history record.

If you cannot guarantee the order, things get complicated, as each trigger would have to: 1) try to insert a new record, and failing that 2) update the existing. You'd have to protect yourself from the intermittent insertion by another trigger and this likely means running within a transaction with serializable isolation level (locking the whole table). This is deadlock-prone, so it's really better to use two history tables, as others already suggested.

Comment: Thanks @MaDa.
Yes CustomerHistory Table have the customerId.
Let me try to keep the changes in one table if not worked then i will try to use two changes.

Comment: @YaqubAhmad The trouble is it WILL work in development, but will give you trouble in production, when traffic increases. Plus I don't know if your DB allows transactions and locking inside triggers - make sure it does.

Answer (score 0):

You should have different *historic* tables for each *normal* table you have. 
Then you can place a trigger in each *normal* table.

Finally, if you need, you can create a view `CustomerHistory` joining the different *historic* tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your trigger to the table where data changes will "trigger" a need to do something.

So a trigger on the Customers table to track CustomerAddress changes and a trigger on CustomerAccountManagers when the ManagerId is changed.